# Why is my text not showing in my DIV?

Tags: javascript, html, css

would you know why the text between my `<p>` tags is not showing in the red DIVs and how to fix this? Many thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/0qLevh83/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="carte-des-soins">
    <ul>
        <li><span class="type-de-soin"><a href="#" data-region="soins-1"> Soins 1</a></span>
        </li>
        <li><span class="type-de-soin"><a href="#" data-region="soins-2"> Soins 2</a></span>
        </li>
        <li><span class="type-de-soin"><a href="#" data-region="soins-3"> Soins 3</a></span>
        </li>
        <li><span class="type-de-soin"><a href="#" data-region="soins-4"> Soins 4</a></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="description-des-soins">
    <div id="soins-1" class="textzone">
        <p>fvfd</p>
    </div>
    <div id="soins-2" class="textzone">
        <p>L'eau minérale</p>
    </div>
    <div id="soins-3" class="textzone">
        <p>Les personnes</p>
    </div>
    <div id="soins-4" class="textzone">
        <p>Les fgd</p>
    </div>
</div>
<p></p>
<br>
<p></p>
<br>
<p></p>
<br>
```

CSS

```
#carte-des-soins {
    background: #ccc;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align: center;

}

#carte-des-soins ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#carte-des-soins li {
    display: inline;
}
#description-des-soins {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 50%;
}
#soins-1, #soins-2, #soins-3, #soins-4 {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 5px 20px 20px 20px;
    width: 650px;
    height: 273px;
    color: #333;
    font: 12px'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1px;
    background: red;
}
#soins-1 h3, #soins-2 h3, #soins-3 h3, #soins-4 h3 {
    color: #3A7CDB;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 18px;
}
#soins-2, #soins-3, #soins-4 {
    display: none;
}
#soins-2 p {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#soins-1 p {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
#soins-1 a {
    color: #3A7CDB;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#soins-1 a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.type-de-soin a:first').css({
        'background-color': '#B4D454',
        'color': '#fff'
    });

    $('.type-de-soin a').click(function () {
        var region = $(this).attr('data-region');

        $('.type-de-soin a').css({
            'background-color': '#fff',
            'color': '#3A7CDB'
        });
        $(this).css({
            'background-color': '#3A7CDB',
            'color': '#fff'
        });

        $('.textzone:visible').stop().fadeOut(500, function () {
            $('#' + region).fadeIn(500);
        });

        return false;

    });

});
```

Comment: thext is there, just scroll your screen to the left

Comment: You've set a css rule #soins-2, #soins-3, #soins-4 {
    display: none;
} that is causing them not to display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You red divs are floated right, and wider than the parent, causing all the content to extend to the left side. You paragraphs are not floated so they're on the left side, but off the screen.

This is what happens when I reduce the `width` of the red divs: http://jsfiddle.net/0qLevh83/3/

Bottom line: **always make sure children elements can fit their parent element**